# Returning all values without duplicates in MySQL

Tags: mysql, database

I'm trying to return all the possible values in a table, but without duplicate values.

`SELECT * FROM optional_hardware;`

Is there any other way I can return all values without duplicate values?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the DISTINCT keyword

```
SELECT DISTINCT column FROM optional_hardware;
```

Comment: Thank you kind sir

Answer (score 2):

You can also use `GROUP BY`

```
SELECT `column` FROM `optional_hardware` GROUP BY `column`
```